# Animation works after disable on the inspector

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate a picture making it float like on this page: http://zurb.com/ink/

This is the class of my div:

```
.graph {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    animation: floating 4s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: floating 4s infinite;
}
```

and this is the div:

```
<div class="graph">
    <img src="img/graph.png">
</div>
```

On Chrome it doesn't work until I stop and play the animation from the checkbox in the inspector. But then it works! It's so frustrating...What could it be? Is it a known bug of Chrome? Why the one on Zurb's page is working? :/

Help!

Comment: it might be some timing issue...u need to use a callback...please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include some javascript to load the animation's css after the page is loaded. 

Why? Because.